# How to analyze complicated type expressions in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, grammar

Things seem to become complicated when dealing with compound C++ types.

For example, how to analyze the type of token `fp` in the codes below?

```cpp
int *f(int *p, int a)
{
    return p + a;
}

int *(*fp())(int *, int)
{
    return f;
};
```

Is there a explanation on syntax for the codes?

Comment: Give it to a tool such as https://cdecl.org/ (it is for C though, I don't know of one that understands all of C++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start on the name, then proceed outwards, handling stuff on the right first, then stuff on the left, except when parentheses change that:

```
       fp                 // `fp` is
       fp()               // (look to the right) a function without parameters, returning
      *fp()               // (look to the left) a pointer to
     (*fp())              // (skip parentheses)
     (*fp())(int *, int)  // (look to the right) a function taking `(int *, int)`, returning
    *(*fp())(int *, int)  // (look to the left) a pointer to
int *(*fp())(int *, int)  // int
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think best way is to not use such complex declaration and use `typedef` or `using` (type alias) to make clear what is an intention:

```cpp
int *f(int *p, int a)
{
    return p + a;
}

using ProgressPointerFunPtr = int* (*)(int *p, int a);
// or pre C++11 style:
// typedef int* (*ProgressPointerFunPtr)(int *p, int a);

ProgressPointerFunPtr fp()
{
    return f;
}
```

This way it is easier to read and it is more clear what code is doing.

Bonus gain is that when you decide to do changes in function pointer it is much easier to do in already existing code, since hunting for places when this change is needed is quicker or not needed at all.